# I get null reference of EditText of a recyclerview item when user clicks on a button of the same item

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have a recycle view name "listadsoffers" in Fragment name "Fragment_Wallet" that contain a list of items every item is layout (adsoffer_item.xml) in this layout I want to save email address entered by user when he click on send request button the problem is that Edit text of email send   a null object reference i have made all my effort and tried many similar question in this forum but i didn't solve the problem

My Adapter class :

```
public class AdsOfferAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdsOfferAdapter.AdsOfferViewHolder>  {
    
        private Retrofit retrofit;
        private RetrofitInterface retrofitInterface;
        Context context;
    
        EditText eagerest ;
    
        ArrayList<AdsOffer> Adsoffers;
        public AdsOfferAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<AdsOffer> AdsOffers) {
    
            this.context = context;
            this.Adsoffers = AdsOffers;
        }
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public AdsOfferViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.adsoffer_item,null);
    
            return new AdsOfferAdapter.AdsOfferViewHolder(view);
        }
        
        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull AdsOfferViewHolder holder, int position) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(util.BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
            retrofitInterface = retrofit.create(RetrofitInterface.class);
    
            final AdsOffer model=Adsoffers.get(position);
            holder.points.setText(model.getPoints()+"");
            holder.name.setText(model.getName());
    
            holder.btnRequest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // here i have the error
                    String email=holder.email.getText().toString();
                    //sendRequest(email)
                }
            });
    
        }
        public class  AdsOfferViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder { // view.onclicklistener
            TextView name;
            TextView points;
            Button btnRequest;
            EditText email;
            ConstraintLayout constraintLayout;
            public AdsOfferViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
    
                name=itemView.findViewById(R.id.nameApp);
                points=itemView.findViewById(R.id.points);
                btnRequest=itemView.findViewById(R.id.sendRequest);
                email =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.emailBox);
    
            }
    
        }
        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return Adsoffers.size();
        }
       }
```

the error throw in this line :

```
                        // here i have the error
                        String email=holder.email.getText().toString();
                        //sendRequest(email)
```

my model class :

```
public class AdsOffer {
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setPoints(int points) {
        this.points = points;
    }

    public AdsOffer(String name, int points) {
        this.name = name;
        this.points = points;
    }


    private String name;
    private int points;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getPoints() {
        return points;
    }
}
```

my adsoffer item adsoffer_item.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".WalletFragment">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="266dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/sendRequest"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_3"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_bold"
            android:text="Send Request"
            android:textColor="@color/primary"
            app:backgroundTint="#FFFFFF"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/emailbox"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/emailbox"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView5" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/emailbox"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/textbox"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_paypal"
            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_bold"
            android:hint="Paypal Email Address"
            android:inputType="textWebEmailAddress|textPersonName"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textColorHint="@android:color/white"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView7" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nameApp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_bold"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView4"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/points"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_bold"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView7"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView7"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView7"
            android:layout_width="89dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_bold"
            android:text="Points :"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/nameApp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_bold"
            android:text="Name App  :"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_bold"
            android:text="5000 points = 15 $"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/emailbox"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/emailbox"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/emailbox" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view2"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="5dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/sendRequest"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/sendRequest"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/sendRequest" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

my fragment layout that contain recycle view i name it listadoffers

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#673AB7"
    tools:context=".WalletFragment">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/listadsoffers"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</FrameLayout>
```

and finally my fragment (fragment wallet) here i initialize my adapter and he displays all items  but when i edit the Edit text and click on button send request here i have this error :
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference

```
    public class WalletFragment extends Fragment {
    
        FragmentWalletBinding binding;
        Context c =null;
       // User user;
        private Retrofit retrofit;
        private RetrofitInterface retrofitInterface;
        ArrayList<AdsOffer> offers=new ArrayList<>();
         AdsOfferAdapter adapter;
        @Override
        public void onAttach(Context context) {
            super.onAttach(context);
            c= context;
        }
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    
        }
    
        public void LoadAdsOffers(AdsOfferAdapter adapter ){
    
           offers.clear();
    
            ProgressDialog dialog;
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
            dialog.setMessage("Please Wait...");
            dialog.show();
    
            retrofitInterface = retrofit.create(RetrofitInterface.class);
            Call<AdsOffer[]> call =  retrofitInterface.GetListOffers();
            call.enqueue(new Callback<AdsOffer[]>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<AdsOffer[]> call, Response<AdsOffer[]> response) {
                    if(response.code()==200){
                        dialog.dismiss();
    
                        binding.listadsoffers.setAdapter(adapter);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        Collections.addAll(offers,response.body());
    
                    }
                }
    
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<AdsOffer[]> call, Throwable t) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), t.getMessage(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
    
    
        }
    
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            binding= FragmentWalletBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater(),container,false);
    
    
            binding.listadsoffers.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getContext(),1));
    
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(util.BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
    
            adapter=new AdsOfferAdapter(c,offers);
            LoadAdsOffers(adapter);
            return binding.getRoot();
        }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's an id mismatch, you are searching for an id but on XML there's a different id

```
email =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.emailBox);

android:id="@+id/emailbox"
```

Comment: OMG !! 2 days of searching for this bug i thought that's a big problem than that